# SQL Select/Join Statement - Select when there is no Join?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So Ive be using this `select` statement:

```
select runners.name, runners.age, sum(races.laptime) as totallaptime
from runners join races on runners.runnerid = races.runnerid
where runners.region = "region001"
group by runners.runnerid
```

This lists all the runners from a specific region and gives a total of all their lap times.

Unfortunately this misses out all the runners in that region who have no lap times yet (presumably because they have no entries in the `races` database).

How can I adjust this `select` statement to get it to include all the runners in a specific region, and list a `0` for `totallaptime` if they havent got any entries in the `races` database?

(Sorry for the vague question title, I couldnt think of any way of summarizing this question)

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select runners.name, runners.age, coalesce(sum(races.laptime),0) as totallaptime
from runners 
left join races on runners.runnerid = races.runnerid
where runners.region = "region001"
group by runners.runnerid
```

A `LEFT JOIN` selects *all rows* of the left table, returning results from the right table if they exist, or a single row with NULL for their values if they do not.

Note: I have added a `COALESCE` to the statement because summing a `NULL` will result in `NULL`; this will change these values into a 0.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which also gives you results from your "left" table (in this case the `runners`) where there is no matching "right" table:

```
select runners.name, runners.age, sum(races.laptime) as totallaptime
from runners LEFT OUTER JOIN races on runners.runnerid = races.runnerid
where runners.region = "region001"
group by runners.runnerid
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit  Have to use LEFT JOIN to include even the non matching records from the left table

```
select runners.name, runners.age, sum(races.laptime) as totallaptime
from runners left join races on runners.runnerid = races.runnerid
where runners.region = "region001"
group by runners.runnerid
```

Comment: A `RIGHT` join with this where clause will act as an `INNER JOIN`.